# Do I have to use &nbsp; for space in Jade?

Tags: pug

I am using Jade and everything is cool except that Jade "eats" my spaces.

For example, in HTML:

```
<b>Hello</b> <b>World</b>
```

or

```
<b>Hello</b>
<b>World</b>
```

Will have a space between "Hello" and "World".

But when converting to Jade it'd be

```
b Hello
b World
```

When rendered as HTML, the space is gone. Like:

```
<b>Hello</b><b>World</b>
```

Do I have to add `&nbsp;` in my Jade template or is there any way I can get a normal space in the generated HTML?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should do it:

```
b Hello
  | World
```

Unfortunately it produces this HTML output in Chrome on my machine:

```
<b>
              Hello
              World</b>
```

But in the end it becomes:

[image]

To come to an end

```
b Hello &nbsp;
b World
```

...will do it too.

Comment: In your second example, the space before the `&nbsp;` means you end up with two spaces in the result.

Comment: I personally dont like the `&nbsp;`- as well as the `2 spaces after the pipe`-solution, but it seems to be the way to do it, if using pug - isn't it? (Hopefully the question is after 10 month still active)

Answer (score 65):

Of course, when you have two of the same tags after each other, you can simply merge them:

```
b Hello World
```

But, if you would have two different sibling tags and would want a space between them, you could use [piping](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#pipedtext) to output a space between them.

For example:

```
b Hello
|     <-- 2 spaces after the pipe
i World
```

Note that when specifying tag contents / piping text, the actual text content is preceded by a white space. This white space is not outputted. So, in effect, to pipe a white-space you need a `|` character followed by **two** spaces.

If you are in an environment where trailing spaces are not preserved, you can alternatively use the following:

```
b Hello
=" "
i World
```

`=` evaluates a JavaScript expression and outputs the result.

Also note that `&nbsp;` is ***not* the same** as a space in HTML. The correct HTML entity to use is `&#32;` (or `&#x20;` if you like hexadecimal numbers).

`&nbsp;` stands for **n**on-**b**reaking **sp**ace. Its character code is 160 (`&#160;`). The difference is that where an ordinary space is used, multiple spaces will be shown as a single space and if a line overflows, the text will continue on the next line.* Non-breaking spaces on the other hand will allways be shown. Lines will never wrap where a non-breaking space is used.

This is best illustrated with an example:

### &nbsp;

```html
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Note the scroll bar at the bottom.)
```

### Space (&#32;)

```html
&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32; (Note there is no scroll bar because all spaces are concatenated into one.)
```

<sub>* This can be overridden with the CSS [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property. Some elements, such as `<pre>`, display all white space and line endings by default.</sub>

Comment: Terrible idea, if your commit removes trailing white space, this breaks your code essentially.

Comment: @user2428118 when working in a distributed environment, you can't control which editor everyone uses. A number of editors (e.g. Atom) strips trailing white space by default, and you can't just assume everybody that will touch your project will change that.

Comment: @Emilien I've added an alternative method for environments that trim trailing spaces.

Comment: @Joseph I've added an alternative method for environments that trim trailing spaces.

Comment: I've removed my down vote as this is actually helpful.

Comment: @user2428118 I've also removed my downvote, as your edit addresses my concern (but I'm still going to continue using `&nbsp;` ;) )

Comment: Regardless of the issue about code stripping, adding silent spaces is dangerous really. The second solution doesn't look as pretty, but it's more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives. One issue with `&nbsp;` is that, if the line gets broken, the `&nbsp;` will still occupy some width. That can result in mis-alignment when you are using `align-right` or `align-center`.

Answer (score 23):

I made a mixin for explicid whitespace:

```
mixin space()
  | !{' '}
```

so you only need to:

```
b Hello
+space
b World
```

Comment: what is a "mixin"?

Comment: That's pretty smart

Comment: Where do you add the mixin?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simpler way:

```
b Hello #{' '}
b world
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want it like this

```
<b>Hello</b>&nbsp;<b>World</b>
```

You should use this

```
b Hello
|&nbsp;
b World
```

Answer (score 0):

This way it will be rendered with space between words:

```
b Hello <-- single space at the end
b world
```

Or use pipe with single space (no need for 2 spaces)

```
b hello
| <-- single space
b world
```