# How to add a space character between two <div>s after Jade rendering?

Tags: html, pug, pugjs

Input:

```
.a text1
.b text2
```

Output will be:

`<div class="a">text1</div><div class="b">text2</div>`

The second `<div>` is just close to the first one without any spaces or LFs.

However, this is what I really want to get:

```
<div class="a">text1</div>
<div class="b">text2</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="a">text1</div> <div class="b">text2</div>
```

Because I need to put a space between them when I use `display:inline-block`. I don't want to set the margin in CSS.

Is it possible to let jade not eat my spaces or LFs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

This block of code

```
.a text1
| &sp;
.b text2
```

compile to

```
<div class="a">text1</div>
&sp;
<div class="b">text2</div>
```

`&sp;` is the medium space ([http://www.w3.org/](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/mathsym.html))

**Update:**
or use this code

```
- var space = ' '
.a text1
| #{space}
.b text2
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because it actually was not entirely correct. You should not use `&sp;`, as it is not exactly the same as a regular space character. The more correct approach is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22220139/339176. TL;DR: use `&nbsp;` if you want a non breaking space, OR use `&#32;` (or `&#x20;` in hex) to get the real space. `&#32;` is what I use in my code and it works great.

Comment: `| #{' '}` I have to write down the full answer comment. It works!. Thanks.

Comment: &sp; actually renders as text on my website literally, while &nbsp; stays invisible.