# &nbsp in jade files shows warnings in node server

Tags: node.js, warnings, pug

I have many `&nbsp;`s' in my jade file and it shows as warnings when i run the node server :

```
Warning: missing space before text for line 210 of jade file "C:\Users\XX\Documents\GitHub\XXX\XX\registerPage.jade"
```

This warnings shows up wherever there is a `&nbsp;`, I don't want it because the logs file generated from server are filled with these warnings.

Comment: Can you post your jade code?

Comment: i read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727360/do-i-have-to-use-nbsp-for-space-in-jade and used "| " , now it doesn't show warnings, but is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and replace all `&nbsp;` to `|` (pipeline followed by space)